# Determine whether the sequence $a_n=4ne^{-4n}$ is increasing or decreasing

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to solve an exercise that asks:

> Determine whether the sequence
> $$a_n=4ne^{-4n}$$
> is increasing or decreasing.

I try starting from
$$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=4(n+1)e^{-4(n+1)}-4ne^{-4n}=4n+4(e^{-4n^2-4n}).
$$
But I honestly don't see a clear way to determine the monotony of the succession, any suggestions? I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1):

You could investigate $f(x)=x e^{-x}$ using the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Put
$$f(x)=xe^{-4x}$$
for $ x\ge 0$.

$ f $ is differentiable and
$$f'(x)=(1-4x)e^{-4x}$$

So
$$x\ge 1\implies f'(x)<0$$

$ f $ is decreasing at $ [1,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the quotient $$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{4(n+1)e^{-4(n+1)}}{4ne^{-4n}}=\frac{(n+1)}{n}e^{-4}\, . $$ If it is greater than $1$, the sequence is increasing, if it is less than $1$, it is decreasing.

There is no need to differentiate anything in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Try differentiation? $f(x) = xe^{-x}$ so $f'(x) = e^{-x}(1-x)$. This function is decreasing if $x > 1$ and increasing. So $n > 1/4$ it will be decreasing.